# Replace character in associate array keys

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

i want to replace underscore with hyphen (dash) in all the keys in my `$array` and nothing else.

Here is my array:

```
Array ( [username] => bob [email] => bob123@gmail.com [first_name] => Bob [last_name] => Jones [picture] => /images/no-picture.png [birthday] => )
```

in this example, i want to replace `[first-name]` with `[first_name]` and ever other key that has a `-` to be replaced with `_`. i **ONLY** want the key an not the value. for example, i do **NOT** want `no-picture.png` because that is a value. thanks!

```
$test = str_replace('-', '_', $array);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) get keys after use [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) bind new keys:

```
<?php
function replaceArrayKeys( $array ) {
    $replacedKeys = str_replace('-', '_', array_keys($array));
    return array_combine($replacedKeys, $array);
}

$array =[
    'username' => 'bob',
    'email' => 'bob123@gmail.com',
    'first-name' => 'Bob',
    'last-name' => 'Jones',
    'picture' => '/images/no-picture.png',
    'birthday' => '1',
];

print_r( replaceArrayKeys($array) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using array_map:

```
function setHyphen(&$array){
   $array= array_combine(array_map(function($str){ return str_replace("_","-",$str); }, array_keys($array)),array_values($array));
}
setHyphen($array);
print_r($array);
```

Ouput:

```
Array ( 
    [username] => bob 
    [email] => bob123@gmail.com 
    [first-name] => Bob 
    [last-name] => Jones 
    [picture] => /images/no-picture.png 
    [birthday] => 123 )
```